# BufferGeometry with hidden vertices is not appearing when vertices are shown

Tags: javascript, three.js

I have a problem with THREE.BufferGeometry. I preallocate large amount of vertices for my needs, and hide them from the screen, by setting their positions outside from the FOV. I've used this trick with ParticleSystem and everything worked fine. But with simple mesh, when I am moving vertices to the FOV nothing happens. I've created a [fiddle to demonstrate the problem](http://jsfiddle.net/xL6S9/9/). In demo when you click on the screen 10 red lines should appear, but you'll never see them until you comment line emptyAttributes(), which moves vertices outside of the FOV.

### Orthographic camera

```
var width = window.innerWidth,
    height = window.innerHeight;
// camera
camera = new THREE.OrthographicCamera(width / -2, width / 2, height / 2, height / -2, 0, 1);
camera.position.x = 0;
camera.position.y = 0;
camera.position.z = 1;
```

### Creating mesh

```
// geometry
var geometry = new THREE.BufferGeometry();
positions = new THREE.Float32Attribute(lines * 4, 3);
colors = new THREE.Float32Attribute(lines * 4, 3);
indices = new THREE.Uint32Attribute(lines * 6, 1);
var radius = 500;

// COMMENT NEXT LINE TO SEE THE LINES
emptyAttributes();
//realAttributes();
geometry.addAttribute('position', positions, 3);
geometry.addAttribute('color', colors, 3);
geometry.addAttribute('index', indices, 1);
// materials
var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
    vertexColors: THREE.VertexColors,
    opacity: 0.8,
    transparent: true
});

// mesh
mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
scene.add(mesh);
```

### Hiding vertices from the screen

```
function emptyAttributes() {
  for (var i = 0; i < lines * 12; i++) {
    if ((i + 1) % 3 == 0) {
        positions.array[i] = 2;
    }
  }
}
```

### Updating attributes to see the lines

```
function realAttributes() {
  for (var i = 0; i < lines; i++) {
    var coords = [i * 10, -100, i * 10 + 5, -100, i * 10 + 5, 100, i * 10, 100];
    for (var j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
        positions.array[i * 12 + j * 3] = coords[j * 2];
        positions.array[i * 12 + j * 3 + 1] = coords[j * 2 + 1];
        positions.array[i * 12 + j * 3 + 2] = 0;

        colors.array[i * 12 + j * 3] = 1;
        colors.array[i * 12 + j * 3 + 1] = 0;
        colors.array[i * 12 + j * 3 + 2] = 0;
    }
    indices.array[i * 6] = i * 4;
    indices.array[i * 6 + 1] = i * 4 + 1;
    indices.array[i * 6 + 2] = i * 4 + 2;
    indices.array[i * 6 + 3] = i * 4;
    indices.array[i * 6 + 4] = i * 4 + 2;
    indices.array[i * 6 + 5] = i * 4 + 3;
  }
}
realAttributes();
mesh.geometry.attributes.position.needsUpdate = true;
mesh.geometry.attributes.color.needsUpdate = true;
mesh.geometry.attributes.index.needsUpdate = true;
```

The problem is reproduced on latest version of THREE.js - r67, in FireFox and Chrome.

Comment: There is a much better way to hide vertices: use `BufferGeometry.drawcalls`. Try this: Populate all your data and then set `geometry.addDrawCall( 0, 6 * lines / 2, 0 );`. This will draw half of the lines. To draw all the lines, on your click event, do this: `mesh.geometry.drawcalls[ 0 ].count = 6 * lines;`. See if that is what you are looking for.

Comment: @WestLangley this is very interesting way, unfortunately I haven't found any documentation or example of it. So I've played a bit with it, and as far as I understand it allows to show some slice of geometry vertices. I'm using my approach for graph visualization and I need to dynamically hide or show edges, which can be located in any part of geometry. I mean I need to show 1,5 and 7 lines at the first draw and on the next draw lines 2,5,6. Is it better to use multiple draw calls for this purpose?

Comment: Better? That's up to you to decide. You could write your own `ShaderMaterial` and use the `discard` statement to discard fragments based on a vertex attribute. That would require only one drawcall.

Comment: You've told that there is a better way to hide them, so I've used your terminology) Thank you for advice anyway, I'll check the discard performance. Regarding to my question, have you got any ideas why is this happening? The only solution was to add one vertex to the FOV on create.